# How can we get my all users favorites count who liked my Tweets from twitter API?

Tags: api, twitter

I have all @screenname and ids for following/friends users. Twitter provide only one API for fetching favorites :
  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json

which returns max 200 objects per request most recent Tweets liked by the authenticating or specified user.
Rate limit for this API is 15 requests per 15 minutes window. We can use since_id or max_id in case of pagination.

My Approach :
    1)  After getting top recent 200 max tweet. I am checking, favorites is for logged in user’s Tweet or not. Each Tweet object have user section which will give owner details. So i can easily check favorites for all Tweets.
2) Basically I need to hit 1 API per user to get that information.

Does anyone know a solution to get the favorite count without hitting that much number of Twitter APIs?

Comment: Hi did you find a solution.